# KEY ERROR on self.cleaned_data.get('file')

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm getting a key error while I'm trying to validate a simple form in Django:

I've tried accessing the file name using:

1. all_clean_data['file']
2. self.cleaned_data.get('file')
3. self.cleaned_data['file']

To no avail. If i'm accessing as a key, I'm getting key error, if I'm using the get method I get None.

Can you please tell my what I'm doing wrong?

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    url_cell_start = forms.IntegerField()
    url_cell_end = forms.IntegerField()
    write_cell_start = forms.IntegerField()
    write_cell_end = forms.IntegerField()
    file = forms.FileField()
    
    def clean(self):
        all_clean_data = super(UploadForm, self).clean()
        url_c_start = all_clean_data['url_cell_start']
        url_c_end = all_clean_data['url_cell_end']
        write_c_start = all_clean_data['write_cell_start']
        write_c_end = all_clean_data['write_cell_end']
        xl_file = all_clean_data["file"]
        extension = os.path.splitext(xl_file.name)[1]
        VALID_EXTENSION = '.xlsx'
        
        if extension.lowercase != VALID_EXTENSION:
            self.add_error('file', 'The file has to be .XLSX')
        
        if (url_c_start is None) or not (url_c_start > 0):
            self.add_error('url_cell_start', 'The URL column needs to be a number grater than zero.')
        
        if (url_c_end is None) or not (url_c_start > 0):
            self.add_error('url_cell_end', 'The URL column needs to be a number grater than zero.')
        else:
            if url_c_start is not None:
                if url_c_end <= url_c_start:
                    self.add_error('url_cell_end',
                                   'The URL-End column need to be a number grater or equal than URL Start')
        
        if (write_c_start is None) or not (write_c_start > 0):
            self.add_error('write_cell_start', 'The URL column needs to be a number grater than zero.')
        else:
            if url_c_end is not None:
                if url_c_end > write_c_start:
                    self.add_error('write_cell_start',
                                   'The URL-Write-start column number needs to be a number grater than URL-cell-end')
        
        if (write_c_end is None) or not (write_c_end > 0):
            self.add_error('write_cell_end', 'The URL column needs to be a number grater than zero.')
        else:
            if write_c_start is not None:
                if write_c_end <= write_c_start:
                    self.add_error('write_cell_end',
                                   'The URL-Write-end column number needs'
                                   ' to be a number grater or equal than URL-Write-start')
        
        return all_clean_data
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after three hours of intensive google searching I've found the solution.

The reason I wasn't getting the key was that haven't added "enctype="multipart/form-data" to the  HTML tag in the template.

Like:

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </form>
```